# nilpotent permutation groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Suppose I have a transitive nilpotent subgroup $G$ of $S_n.$ What can be said about cycle types of elements in $G?$ We know that $G$ does not contain any transpositions (since $S_n$ is not nilpotent), but what else can we say?

Comment: If you consider the case $n = p^{a}$ for a prime $p$ and a positive integer $a,$ then  Sylow $p$-ssubgroup of $S_{n}$ is n iterated wreath product ( $a$ times ) of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with itself. The cycle types are easy to determine in that case, and this is probably the most complicated case of your question. Also, your statement that $G$ contains no transpositions is not correct. A Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_{4}$ contains transpositions, for example.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson The real question is more algorithmic. Suppose you have a machine which spits out cycle types in $G$ (the question comes from Galois Theoretic considerations, so the machine is just factoring your mystery polynomial mod various primes $p$). Presumably, certain cycle type will mean that your group is definitely **not** nilpotent, and if you keep not getting the bad cycle type, your group *is* nilpotent with high probability.

Comment: Elements in the centre will be fixed-point-free, so a natural question would be how many fixed-point-free elements you might expect to get. (Fixed-point-free elements also being known as *derangements*, if you want to check the literature.) I would expect that there would be many derangements in a transitive nilpotent group, and you can see here -- http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/fixed.pdf -- that at least $1/2$ of the elements of the group are derangements. I don't know how much this bound could be improved... And, more generally, I'm not sure how much more you could hope to say...

Comment: @NickGill That is interesting, but not quite sufficient algorithmically, since $1/e$ of the elements in $S_n$ are derangements, and so it might take many trials to see the difference between $1/2$ and $1/e,$ especially since the variance is not so easy to compute, probably...

Comment: I do not think ( at least in the case that $n$ is a prime power) that any particular cycle type for a $p$-element forces the group not to be nilpotent- after all, that $p$-element lies in some Sylow $p$-subgroup- much the same point as I was making in my comment above. For your algorithmic question, it may be useful to note that ( by Baer-Suzuki) a finite group is nilpotent if and only if its two-generator subgroups are al nilpotent.

Comment: If you find an element $g$ of prime order $p$ that does not divide $n$ then $G$ is not nilpotent. More generally, $G$ is not nilpotent if the number of fixed points of $g$ is not divisible by $\alpha$ where $n=p^k\alpha$ with $p \not| \alpha$. I would expect this to quickly rule out "most" non-nilpotent groups. On the other hand, if $G$ is acting regularly, then you cannot decide nilpotence by looking at single elements.

Comment: @DerekHolt But you are not looking at a single elements, you are looking at a *collection* of conjugacy classes in $S_n$ that $G$ intersects. Presumably, some collections are forbidden, even though any single class in the collection are OK.

Comment: The point I was making was that if $G$ is acting regularly and is not nilpotent, then you will never be able to say with certainty that $G$ is not nilpotent, because $G$ could be cyclic of order $n$. But you will be able to make probabilistic statements. So perhaps the question you should be asking is how many elements do you need to look at in order to be able to say that the probability that $G$is or is not nilpotent is less than some user-specified $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, you are correct!